# Enum exhaustive check fails when Enum is Generic

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

In TypeScript you can check Enums exhaustively (for example in switch statements).

### Problem

I need to use the Enum as Generic because I want to restrict other parameters according to the provided `enumVal`.

I know that for this simple example it'd easiest to just overload the function accordingly, but this becomes impractical when there are many possible combinations.
For example for the following enum:

### Example

```
enum MyEnum {
  FOO = 'foo',
  BAR = 'bar'
}
```

this works:

```
function exhaustiveSwitch(enumVal: MyEnum) {
  switch (enumVal) {
    case MyEnum.FOO:
      break
    case MyEnum.BAR:
      break
    default:
      const _exhaustiveCheck: never = enumVal
  }
}
```

But when I use the Enum as Generic, it says `Type 'EnumVal' is not assignable to type 'never'`:

```
function exhaustiveSwitchGeneric<EnumVal extends MyEnum> (enumVal: EnumVal) {
  switch (enumVal) {
    case MyEnum.FOO:
      break
    case MyEnum.BAR:
      break
    default:
      const _exhaustiveCheck: never = enumVal //Type 'EnumVal' is not assignable to type 'never'
  }
}
```

(check out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=15#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClAYgeR1AXigHIAzAe3OIBoMoAhAQQCVCSAjAQwCdi0BfNGlJgQAYwAuAS3IgowAB4ALTmADO0gG7AAygHcpEsUoAUoSADVOAGwBcsRMgCUUdJjUGjSqGeRXrLm6YUGKcasAOSJAAdLg4tnTBUOzcwJwA1okhYRHwURDRTMwJSZgpaZlJACbApKrWEiWlYrIaUAD6iirqWsAAwkrAYun2IMDa3GzmEP50goLCopIycl2qGlLa+obGAOKgwNxSYgA8+f7yChKgVWqRyAB8PtP+9uc2gXQeO96+lh+uLKhcL3GJxJpJcoZIE5UEFIoQ4JQyrBGp1MANRGYFogNqdZTrXoDIYjKBjCZTPw2OYCNBAA))

### Question

1. Why does this not work when using the Enum as Generic?
2. Is there another way to use the exact provided value (i.e. `MyEnum.FOO`) for another parameter without Generics? (excluding function overloading)

There may well be a good reason, but to my understanding using a Generic this way should result in the same outcome as using it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is even bigger. There is no possibility to extend Enums in TypeScript, there is no syntax for that and it is not supported, therefor your code `EnumVal extends MyEnum` will work only for `MyEnum`. If you want to extend some variant, create literal union like `'foo' | 'bar'`, then the extends has a sense.

Below a prove of no possibility to extends Enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
  FOO = 'foo',
  BAR = 'bar'
}

enum MySubEnum {
  FOO = 'foo',
}

type MySubEnumExtendsMyEnum = MySubEnum extends MyEnum ? true : false // false
exhaustiveSwitchGeneric(MySubEnum.FOO)
// compile error: 
// Argument of type 'MySubEnum' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyEnum'.
```

And last bad news - exclusive switch is not possible with generics. But fortunately we can do some workaround. Below example is using string literals as I said, there is no possibility to extends Enum. Consider:

```
type MyVariant = 'foo' | 'bar';
type SubVariant = 'foo';

type SubVariantExtendsMyVariant = SubVariant extends MyVariant ? true : false; // true

function exhaustiveSwitchGeneric<Val extends MyVariant>(val: Val) {
  const v = val as MyVariant // important line
  switch (v) {
    case 'foo':
      break
    case 'bar':
      break
    default:
      const _a: never = v;
  }
}
```

We have a trick working by `val as MyVariant`, switch is exclusive and needs to have all variants of `MyVariant`

Comment: Your workaround is working perfectly (also with Enums by using `const _enumVal = enumVal as MyEnum`). Thank you!

While extending enums would be great imo, as it is, I would expect exhaustive checks to then work when using generics (provided it is an enum).